# How to solve a diophantine equation pair?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I know how to solve basic linear diophantine equations, but how would one solve this?:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rrrr}
x &+& y &+& z &=& 31 \\
x &+& 2y &+& 3z &=& 41
\end{array}
\end{equation}
$$
I tried subistituting the $x$ from the lower one to the upper one but I don't know how I would then get the answers for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subtracting both equations we get $$y+2z=10$$ Can you proceed?

Comment: I can solve the y's and the z's from that, but I don't know how to get the x's.

Comment: you can plug them in one of the two equations

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $y+2z=10$ should be easy to solve.

Comment: You should add that you subtracted the first equation from the second equation. Additionally, you can mention how it can follow from there.